# Permanent Delete Option Not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When I permanent delete a Post in Laravel using this syntax in the Controller method it will give me an error same code working for restore method

```
public function permanentDelete($id=null){
    $post = Post::where('id',$id)->forceDelete();
    if($post){
        return Redirect::to('post/trash')->with('message','Records Deleted permenantly');
    }else{
        return Redirect::to('post/trash')->with('message','Error in deleting a record');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error thrown?

Comment: There is no error being thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like, the record you are trying to `forceDelete` is already soft deleted. In the cases similar to that soft deleted records are not retrieved by the query. You may try the following

```
Post::where('id',$id)->withTrashed()->forceDelete()
```

It will make sure that the soft deleted records are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
Post::find($id)->forceDelete();
```

This will look for the post with a certain id and will only select one row.

Answer (score 0):

I delete registers this way:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->data->find($id)->delete();
        return Redirect::route('data.index');
    }
```

Hope this help someone.